# Number of comparisons in mergesort in R

Tags: r, sorting

i am writing a merge sort in R. I have 2 functions. The first is mergelist()

```
mergelist <- function(a, b)
{
    al <- length(a$data)
    bl <- length(b$data)        
    r <- numeric(al + bl)
    numberOfComparisions <-0
    ai <- 1
    bi <- 1
    j <- 1

    while((ai <= al) && (bi <= bl))
    {
        if(a$data[ai]<b$data[bi])
        {
            r[j] <- a$data[ai]
            ai <- ai + 1
            numberOfComparisions  = numberOfComparisions + 1
        }
        else
        {
            r[j] <- b$data[bi]
            bi <- bi + 1    
            numberOfComparisions  = numberOfComparisions  + 1
        }       
        j <- j + 1
    }
    if(ai<=al)
    r[j:(al+bl)] <- a$data[ai:al]    
    else if(bi <= bl)
    r[j:(al+bl)] <- b$data[bi:bl]    

    returnList <- list(number=numberOfComparisions  + a$number + b$number , data = r)
    return(returnList)
}
```

This methods takes in 2 sorted lists as parameter a and b and returns a sorted list with the number attribute of the list telling me how many comparisions there have been made.

I also have this method mergesort()

```
mergesort <- function(x)
{
    l <- length(x)

    if(l > 1)   {
        p <- ceiling(1/2)
        a <- mergesort(x[1:p])          
        b <- mergesort(x[(p+1):l])
        return(mergelist(a,b))      
    }
    lister <- list(number=0, data = x)
    return(lister)
}
```

Which takes in a vector x and sorts it. It is returning a list just like mergelist() with the number attribute being the same as in mergelist.

Now my problem is that i have following example: `mergesort(c(11,10,9,15,6,12,17,8,19,7))` ,

Which should return

```
$number [1] 22
$data [1] 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 15 17 19
```

But it returns

```
$number
[1] 30

$data
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 15 17 19
```

So this means it counts a comparision where it shouldn´t. I don´t know where. Can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't your code

```
p <- ceiling(**1**/2)
```

be like this

```
p <- ceiling(**l**/2)
```

Comment: glad that it helped :)